# Instagram Public Api ( __a=1 ) is banned. Any alternative?

Tags: php, json, instagram, instagram-api

I used Instagram public API (adding `__a=1` to parameters of an URL) to get a post detail (`caption` ,`imageUrl`, `postType`, `likes`, `comments` , `viewsCount`). But it seems that Instagram banned that recently and returned a 403. It also asks for login when I try to directly open a post by its usrl.

I tried to use the Instagram private API (https://mgp25.github.io/) for getting post details, but after some requests Instagram banned that too:

> "throttled by instagram because of too many api requests"

Do you have any offer for an alternative?

Comment: Looks more like they just banned you for spamming their API

Comment: yes, but I was using this API for more than one year at the same rate of requests and there were no problem. Maybe there is a new limit

Comment: `__a=1` is a public endpoint API. How did he notice you and banned you? This API `__a=1` is also not found in instagram documents! How long have you been using this API `__a=1`?

Comment: Maybe by my ip or something (since it is also banned when I use psihpone proxy on my own pc, but it allows me when I try without proxy)

Comment: I was using it for about tow years

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is not really banned but now redirects with 302 to auth page. It seems like auth is required when Instagram account and query geoIPs are different. Alternative is to use official API. No scraping can be done, because the profile link now also requires authentication. You can do authenticated scraping but you are limited to 200 queries ( that Instagram sends to get data) per hour.

Comment: Is there any reference for 200 query per hour limit? or any document about instagram app limits

Comment: @Saeed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting#platform-rate-limits

Comment: It also does not work in Russia, Belarus and Kazakhstan.

Comment: When I open a direct link, it works. If I try to load json using the program - it does not work.

Comment: Faced the same issue. When performing a request from heroku server I'm getting login page. But from my personal Russian IP everything works. However if I'm adding cookie into the headers then it works even from US IP but it's not a stable solution.

Comment: It seems like Instagram makes a desicion upon  geoIP of your request and your Instagram account. So if u registered and accesssed it in one country and town, but then trying to get data via public grap api from the server located in another country - it will require to be authenticated

Answer (score 3):

Instagram blocked all public endpoints with some limitations and hit rate. Now you need to send the user's session to get the response.

***Did you notice the same endpoint returning the JSON response when you are logged in on Instagram in the same browser? Yes, that because whenever you are hitting the URL like "https://www.instagram.com/anything/?__a=1", your browser sending the live and valid sessionid to Instagram. Since you are logged in hence Instagram served you well.***

Ever you wonder why the same endpoint started to work again after changing the Internet connection from Wifi to Mobile hotspot or try with another internet service provider.

It's because your IP got blocked and no more free hot babes for you until you are logged in.

**Below is the PHP code to give a try with sessionid.**

```php
<?php
// keyword or user name
$hashtag = $username = "msevylynch";
// $endpoint = "explore/tags/$hashtag"; // hashtag search
$endpoint = $username; // user search
// login in insta account and copy session from browser's cookie tab
$sessionid = '<YOU-SESSION-ID-PICK-FROM-BROWSER-AFTER-LOGIN>';

$ch = curl_init();
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/msevylynch/?__a=1
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.instagram.com/{$endpoint}/?__a=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Cookie: ds_user='.$username.'; igfl='.$username .'; sessionid=' . $sessionid,
    'User-Agent: Instagram 7.16.0 Android'
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $response;
?>
```

***Still no luck then it means*** *Instagram blocked you or your IP for some time due to*

1. ***hitting endpoint too early or very fast programmatically***
2. ***denied the presented challenge***
3. ***seems it's an automated hit***
4. ***password is changed***
5. ***you are logged out***
6. ***or your internet bill is over due .. ha ha ha***

Thank you for the reading this long, much apriceated.

Comment: I'm able to hit the endpoint from a private browser with no session data just fine, I don't think this is correct.

Comment: Hi @CWSites, sooner or later you will be asked to solve captcha or do log in or would see the error. It may be an IP block too.

Answer (score 2):

Instagram is getting very strict with __a=1 endpoint. Your best bet in 2021 to get Instagram profile info is to use clean residential proxies

Comment: would you please name some other cloud proxy services ?

Answer (score 0):

try using "?__a=1&__d=dis"

thank me later.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34080430)

Answer (score 0):

**Use /channel** page to get JSON data of the user profile.

https://www.instagram.com/imvickykumar999/channel/?__a=1&__d=1

Comment: I still can not access this in an incognito window. `{"message":"Please wait a few minutes before trying again.","require_login":true,"status":"fail"}`