# How to use new Instagram API to fetch last 8 images & links to them without authenticating?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram, instagram-graph-api

With the new Instagram API overhaul as of June 2020. The way to scrape instagram is unclear to me. I'm still using code I had from before that date and it works some of the time but when I reload the page though some of the time i get a CORS issue, why is it working sometimes but not other times??

```
<div id="instagram-photos" class="instagram-photos"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const instagramRegExp = new RegExp(/<script type="text\/javascript">window\._sharedData = (.*);<\/script>/)

  const fetchInstagramPhotos = async (accountUrl) => {
    // get request to our instagram public page
    const response = await axios.get(accountUrl)

    // response.data contains page source code, we find the script that contains the posts data using regex & jsonify it
    // a capturing group regex returns an array with the whole matched string in the first item, then each matched group content after, here there is one match.
    const json = JSON.parse(response.data.match(instagramRegExp)[1])

    //find the array with the posts and at position 0 splice the first 12 into a new array
    const edges = json.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.splice(0, 7)


    const photos = edges.map(({ node }) => {
      return {
        url: `https://www.instagram.com/p/${node.shortcode}/`,
        thumbnailUrl: node.thumbnail_src,
        displayUrl: node.display_url,
        caption: node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node.text
      }
    })
    return photos
  }

  (async () => {
    try {
      const photos = await fetchInstagramPhotos('https://www.instagram.com/abcdef/')
      const container = document.getElementById('instagram-photos')
      let n = 1;
      photos.forEach(el => {
        const a = document.createElement('a')
        const img = document.createElement('img')

        a.setAttribute('href', el.url)
        a.setAttribute('target', '_blank')
        a.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener noreferrer')
        a.classList.add('instagram-photo')
        a.classList.add('post' + n)


        img.setAttribute('src', el.thumbnailUrl)
        img.setAttribute('alt', el.caption)

        a.appendChild(img)
        container.appendChild(a)
        n++;
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Fetching Instagram photos failed', e)
    }
  })()


</script>
```

How can websites like this scrape instagram without using any user access tokens or authenticating the app with my instagram account?? I thought the whole point of the overhaul was to stop this from being possible?
https://apps.elfsight.com/panel/applications/instashow

Answer (score 3):

`https://instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1` use this to fetch the json data of a user and get the posts by them including the image urls

Comment: all you've changed is added ?__a=1 then

Comment: thats actually banned.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016243/instagram-public-api-a-1-is-banned-any-alternative

Comment: only works for the first request.. then they hit u with CORS

Comment: It's not banned, I can hit that API just fine in the browser without authenticating.