# AXIOS GET request to instagram not working in prod

Tags: express, axios, instagram, vercel

I am stuck for a few hours and I can't find an answer.

It's a very simple request that works fine in the browser (it returns a JSON answer), for example :
https://www.instagram.com/eurosportfr/channel/?__a=1

In dev the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/instagram', (req, res) => {
 
  async function getInstagramFeed() {
    await axios
      .get('https://www.instagram.com/eurosportfr/?__a=1')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        res.write(`${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
        res.end();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response);
        res.write('<h1>ERROR GRAVE</h1>');
        res.write(err.response);
        res.end();
      });
  }

  getInstagramFeed();
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));
```

The result in DEV ENV is JSON data with all what I need.

But in production, it doesn't return me the JSON. Instead it returns me an HTML page...

You can try it here: (I display in the body the result)
https://corsmiddleware.vercel.app/instagram

When I try another api request with another API client, it works just fine in prod, example :
https://corsmiddleware.vercel.app/test

Any idea ??

Thanks

Comment: I think in development mode, you are logged in instagram while in prod env you are not. You can test it by pasting the url you provide in browser (incognito mode). You will get the login page which is same as production return

Comment: Hi Mic Fung, thanks for your reply.

I tried even if I am not logged, even in Incognito mode, and it works just fine on localhost, but in production not...

I noticed that locally before I get the JSON, it also displays the html results for half a second.

Comment: I read this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016243/instagram-public-api-a-1-is-banned-any-alternative
may be related to geolocation. For me, login is required to get your link works.
See if you can change your server location to where you are or maybe in france to get rid of the login problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helped me understand the issue, I will make a global answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This request now requires authentification. It was working in the past, and it's still actually working here in Morocco where I am, but this solution is not reliable.

The solution is to follow the instructions on facebook :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/